# Google Docs: Search By Publication Status

Tags: google-drive

I would like to search my Google Docs for documents which I have published, but I don't see a way to search for or sort by this characteristic. This is different from documents which I have shared with collaborators or viewers. I want to see documents which I have published to a public docs.google.com URL.

How can I search for documents which are published?

Comment: Doesn't shared by me offer this feature ?

Comment: @phwd - no, this doesn't actually return published documents. Weird, they only offer me "Private (not shared)", "Shared by me", "Shared with me" and "Shared with everyone in my domain" in the search options. Published would be a very sensible option to have there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on search options next to the search button, one of the filter options is "search". Change the drop down to "Owned by me". Then change the "Sharing" drop down to "shared by me". That should show you all items you own that you've shared - hence items you've published.

Comment: A work around - but the only solution as far as I can tell. Upvote.

Comment: This does most of what I want - thank you!  Unfortunately, future readers of this answer should know that currently, the "Search" dropdown with options "All Items; Owned by me; Starred; Hidden; Trash" is hideously broken.  "All items" in that drop-down does not mean "all items," and "Owned by me" doesn't mean "all items owned by me" - both exclude things that show up in the "Hidden" category. Is it too much to ask that "all" mean "all," Google?